# High CPU consumption by Apache Tika

Tags: java, apache-tika, tika-server, tika-python

I am using [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/index.html) to extract text from PDF files.
My problem is that the Tika service shows CPU spikes from 100-400% in Linux.

I'm using [Tika 2.9.1](https://tika.apache.org/2.9.1/index.html), which is the latest stable version of Tika. I also observed the same CPU spikes when using [Tika 1.20](https://tika.apache.org/1.20/index.html).

I'm using this section of code to get text from PDF file:

```
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(new File("Example.pdf"));
ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();
  
//parsing the document using PDF parser
PDFParser pdfparser = new PDFParser(); 
pdfparser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata,pcontext);
  
//getting the content of the document
System.out.println("Contents of the PDF :" + handler.toString());
```

Is there any parameter that I can set to reduce Tika's CPU usage?

Comment: what is difference in using tika and tika-server ?

Comment: Are you using Tesseract to do OCR of any images in the PDF?

Comment: I am using plain tika-app jar file. I am not sure if it uses Tesseract to do OCR of images in pdf.

Comment: Running tika-app in batch mode does not help. The cpu consumption is still high.

Comment: Do you have Tesseract installed? Did you disable or configure it?

Comment: I have tried with default config and also I tried adding custom config with following code block - 
<parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser">
<parser-exclude class="org.apache.tika.parser.ocr.TesseractOCRParser"/>
</parser>

But in both the cases cpu consumption is 300-400% for a pdf file / doc file.

Comment: I don't have Tesseract installed on my system

Comment: @Gagravarr 
Apache Tika internally uses Apache PDFBox.
So I tried extracting text from same pdf file using Apache PDFBox 3.0.2 and it shows that cpu usage is 300-400%.
This issue is reproducible with pdf file of size 351KB and 44MB.

Comment: Please share the PDF file.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr 
For a small size pdf file try downloading 500KB pdf file from this url = https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-documents-download/sample-pdf-download/

For a large size pdf file of around 44MB try downloading a pdf from this url = https://elearning.sist.ac.ke/ebooks/ebooks/financial-management-by-i-m-pandey/

For both these pdf files I get 300-400% CPU usage. I have tried using tika-app jar file directly with this command =

java -jar tika-app-2.9.1.jar --text pdffilename.pdf

Comment: I tried both files with pdfbox and tika and CPU usage went up to 47% at the beginning, then stayed around 13%, and finished after a few seconds. My CPU can't go over 100% on Windows.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Do you have 8 core system ? Is tika-app initally using 4 core completely when overall cpu usage is 47% and then does tika-app uses 1 core completely when the overall cpu usage is 13% ?
Is there any way we can bring down this CPU usage of tika-app ?

Comment: I have a 16 core system (8 physical cores). Java itself likely using concurrency to be more efficient, tika /pdfbox itself are not when it is about a single file. I do not understand the complaint. IMHO it would be best if any software would use as much capabilities as possible so that the job gets finished faster.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @TilmanHausherr. 
I am running apache tika on a system that has low resources and it has multiple other processes running , that's why I am concerned about high CPU usage. 
I wanted to understand if by any means we can improve apache tika performance in terms of CPU usage. Do you know if we can use AOT(ahead of time) compliation method with apache pdfbox or apache tika ? I could not find any resources that explain how can I convert pdfbox or apache tika JAR file into a executable using "jaotc" or any other AOT compiler.

Comment: I don't know, sorry. But I think this is a question outside of java, i.e. how to limit CPU usage by a process.